# QListWidget Insert Items

Tags: c++, qt, loops, qlistwidget

I am trying to add two items into my QListWidget dynamically. However, the following codes only allow me to add only the last item into the list. `strList.size()` contains 4 items. Assuming `name` contains "ABC 1" and "ABC 2".

Is my loop incorrect? Or is my method of adding items into the `listWidget` wrong?

.h:

```
public:
    QListWidgetItem *item[2];
```

.cpp:

```
...
while(!xml.atEnd())
{
    xml.readNextStartElement();
    if(xml.isStartElement())
    {
        if(xml.name() == "OS")
        {
            strList << xml.readElementText();
        }
    }
}


int num = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < strList.size(); i++)
{
    if(strList[i] == "ABC")
    {
        QString name = strList[i] + strList[i+1];

        item[num] = new QListWidgetItem();
        item[num]->setText(name);
        ui.listWidget->insertItem(num, item[num]);
        num += 1;
    }
}
```

Output (listWidget):

> ABC02

Expected output (listWidget):

> ABC01 ABC02

Comment: What are the contents of `strList`?

Comment: @thuga `strList` is a string list that contains `ABC, 01, ABC, 02`

Comment: @thuga It always seemed to only insert the second item. In the listWidget, there's only ABC02 in it.

Comment: Try debugging. Either set a break point on your `for` loop and go step by step, or put some debug messages in your `for` loop to check if `strList[i]` is actually `"ABC"` in the cases where your expect them to be.

Comment: I tried your exact code and worked for me. Maybe you are doing something else with you list afterwards???

Comment: @thuga Yes, I checked that `strList[i]` is actually `ABC`. I would think that something has went wrong during the insertion of the list items (e.g. `ui.listWidget->insertItem(num, item[num]);`

Comment: `strList[i+1]` - memory corruption

Comment: @dim_gr It works on your side? Perhaps I need to check again. I could only see one item in my list.

Comment: Could you post the code when you fill the strList? or the code after the code you posted??

Comment: @dim_gr I'm actually reading in strings from a xml. I will edit the original post to put in the reading of `strList`.

Comment: Yes it might probably be an initial wrong `strList`...

Comment: Try to print out the contents of `strList` after filling it from XML and before the `for` loop to see if the contents are correct...